# Most apt word for "sexual humour"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, humor

What is the most apt word to describe sexual humour in a movie?

Comment: In addition to *Bawdy* and *risqué* that JLG has offered (which I think are fine words) there is simply the term *adult humor* which usually means *sexual* and always means *not suitable for kids*.

Comment: See also [Adult Swim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_Swim).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Bawdy* means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bawdy) "(of language, plays, etc.) containing references to sex, especially to be humorous."

Or if the film being described is a little more risqué, there is [*ribald*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ribald), which means "coarse, obscene, or licentious, usually in a humorous or mocking way."

Comment: Then, too, there's "blue".

Comment: @Bill In the northeast US, *blue* includes both sexual humor and non-sexual language, such as obscenities, that is not appropriate for formal situations.  *Blue* would be a lot less specific than *bawdy*.  It may be different where you are though.

Comment: @KitFox♦: I'm in Taiwan but from the NE USA. When I think of "blue" humor, I think of bluenosed Puritans, who are always frowning at anything sexual, but you're right about it being broader than _bawdy_. "Obscenity" according to M-W: "Related to OBSCENITY: Synonyms: bawdiness, **blueness**, coarseness, crudeness, crudity, dirt, dirtiness, filth, filthiness, foulness, grossness, impureness, impurity, indecency, lasciviousness, lewdness, nastiness, profanity, raunch, raunchiness, ribaldry, smut, smuttiness, vulgarity, wantonness". **Scatological & sexual language.**

Answer (score 0):

Ribald, if referring to sexual humor being used in a crude or irreverent manner, Look it up.  However with America's decline in education, people might not know what it means.

Comment: This is mentioned in JLG's answer above: "Or if the film being described is a little more risqué, there is ***ribald***, which means 'coarse, obscene, or licentious, usually in a humorous or mocking way.' "